# Any assured method for finding the derivative of p Euclidian norms?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Assuming both $y$ and $\beta$ are $p \times 1$ vectors, and $W$ is a $p \times p - 2$ matrix, how would one take the first derivative of this: $L(\beta) = || y - \beta||^2_2 + || W\beta||^2_2$.

I'm aware that this essentially means $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta} \sum_{i = 1}^p (y_i - \beta_i)^2 + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta} || W\beta||^2_2$.

After looking online, I found that the identity of $||A\mathbf{x}||^2_2 = 2A^TA\mathbf{x}$. While this is suffice for my proofs, I fail to understand *why* this is the case. I do know that this will apply to $|| W\beta||^2_2$.

So my question is how to differentiate $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta} \sum_{i = 1}^p (y_i - \beta_i)^2$ in a very straightforward and logical way, with fundamentals that I can apply to other $p$-value norms at any time without worrying about identities and such.

Many thanks, this has been driving me utterly mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta}$ will be a vector with entries $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_k}$, in this case for $k=1,\ldots, p$. We can calculate $$\frac{\partial }{\partial \beta_k}\sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-\beta_i)^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k} (y_k-\beta_k)^2 = -2(y_k-\beta_k).$$ This is because $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}$ means to take the derivative with respect to the variable $\beta_k$ while treating all other $\beta_i$s as constants. And each $y_i$ is truly a constant. So only the $i=k$ term varies with $\beta_k$.

For $\|W\beta\|_2^2$, we need to first note that if $v$ is a vector with entries $v_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n$, then $\|v\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$. We then note that the $i^{th}$ entry of $W\beta$ is $\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j$, so $$\|W\beta\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \bigl(\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j\bigr)^2.$$ Here, $W_{i,j}$ is the row $i$, column $j$ entry of $W$.  We need to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}$ of this, which is $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2\bigl(\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j\bigr) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}\Bigl[\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j\Bigr]=\sum_{i=1}^n 2\bigl(\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j\bigr) \cdot w_{i,k}.$$ Here we just use power rule (so the exponent of $2$ comes down as a factor) and chain rule (we multiply by the derivative of the function inside the square). Again, to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}\sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,j}\beta_j$, we note that only the $j=k$ term survives.

One can check directly by playing with lots of indices that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_k}\|W\beta\|_2^2= 2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^p w_{i,p}w_{i,j}\beta_j$$ is the row $k$ entry of $2W^TW\beta$, which is the identity you wrote.

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you. I have a follow up - how would we go about rewriting L(beta) by reference to L_j(beta) (i.e. the loss for a single instance of y_j)? Do we need to incorporate the summations above? So far it's as simple to me as saying 'sum from 1...p the squared norms of y-beta and Wbeta for a single instance of y'

Comment: The $j^{th}$ coordinate of $W\beta$ is $\sum_{i=1}^p w_{j,i}\beta_i$. We can decompose $L(\beta)$ into summands of the form $$|y_j-\beta_j|+\Bigl|\sum_{i=1}^p w_{j,i}\beta_i\Bigr|^2.$$  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially coming back to the definition of the differential
$$\|A(y_0+h)\|^2=\|Ay_0\|^2+2\langle Ay_0,Ah\rangle+\|Ah\|^2$$$$=
\|Ay_0\|^2+2\langle A^TAy_0,h\rangle +o(h)$$ Thus the differential of  $y\mapsto \|Ay\|^2$ calculated at the point $y_0$is the linear form $h\mapsto 2\langle A^TAy_0,h\rangle$ or, equivalently, the gradient of $y\mapsto \|Ay\|^2$ calculated at the point $y_0$ is $2A^TAy_0.$

Answer (score 0):

The Frobenius $(:)$ product is extremely useful in *Matrix Calculus*
and has these properties
$$\eqalign{
\def\b{\beta}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
   \;=\; \operatorname{Trace}\LR{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \|B\|_F^2 \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
}$$
Calculating the differential of the Frobenius norm is easy using this product
$$\eqalign{
d\,\|B\|_F^2 &= d\LR{B:B} \\&= B:dB + dB:B \\&= 2B:dB \\
}$$
Use this result to calculate the differential of the $L$ function and recover its gradient
$$\eqalign{
 L &= \LR{\b-y}:\LR{\b-y} \;+\; \LR{W\b}:\LR{W\b} \\
dL &= 2\LR{\b-y}:{d\b} \;+\; 2\LR{W\b}:\LR{W\,d\b} \\
   &= 2\LR{\b-y}:{d\b} \;+\; 2\LR{W^TW\b}:d\b \\
\frac{\p L}{\p\b} &= 2\b-2y \;+\; 2W^TW\b \\
}$$